# Objective-C messaging, smartly dealing with unknown messages

Tags: objective-c, runtime, messaging, conceptual

Is there a way to do something similar to KVC but use the message name as the key itself? For example, rather than `valueForKey:`, is there a way for an object to respond to all messages?

For example, say you have an XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ...>
<employees>
  <employee>
    <name>Bill</name>
    <department>Accounting</department>
  </employee>
  <employee>
    <name>John</name>
    <department>Human Resources</department>
  </employee>
</employees>
```

Besides using the already-available NSXMLDocument and co., would there be a way to implement some sort of abstraction so you could do:

```
MyXML *xmlDoc = [[MyXML alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"test.xml"];

NSLog (@"%@", [[[xmlDoc employees] first] department]);

[[[xmlDoc employees] first] setDepartment:@"Management"];
```

I chose XML just as an example, but I want to know whether this is possible at all, and whether or not it involves getting too close to the Objective-C runtime or whether it is supported by the runtime itself, and how I would go about implementing something like this. This is purely for experimental purposes and I understand that there will likely be significant performance costs.

**EDIT:**
If possible, I'd like to avoid existing frameworks such as Cocoa and use the base Objective-C object `Object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `forwardInvocation:` and `methodSignatureForSelector:` to handle unrecognized messages. It is [described](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/forwardInvocation:) in the `NSObject` reference.

EDIT: Wikipedia has an [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Forwarding) of how forwarding can be accomplished for Object, basically by implementing `forward:` and `performv:`.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful info, but that's specific to Cocoa, I'm looking for an overall Objective-C use. For example, compiling just straight Objective-C in Linux or Windows or Mac.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to codelogic, I've found out all you need to do for GCC's Objective-C runtime is:

```
#import <obc/Object.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface RespondsToEverything : Object {}
@end

@implementation RespondsToEverything
- (retval_t) forward:(SEL) sel :(arglist_t) argFrame
{
    fprintf (stderr, "Received: %s\n", get_sel_name (sel));
}
@end

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    id test = [RespondsToEverything new];
    [test asdfasdfasdfasdf];
    [test zxcvzxcvzxcvzxcv];

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Received: asdfasdfasdfasdf
Received: zxcvzxcvzxcvzxcv
```

But of course, GCC complains that it cannot find method signatures for `asdfasdfasdfasdf` and `zxcvzxcvzxcvzxcv`. Not a big deal, it still shows that the concept is doable. In Apple's runtime you can use `sel_getName(sel)` instead of `get_sel_name(sel)`.